# Psshutdown not working in batch files

Tags: batch-file

As I stated above Psshutdown refuses to work in a batch file but works fine in a command prompt. The script has some light logic to determine what group of PCs and such. Here is the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "C:\temp\remote enable rdp"
goto :SET

:SET
set /p groupPC=pc or list?:
if %groupPC% == pc goto :PC
if %groupPC% == list goto :LIST
goto :SKIP

:PC
ECHO[
set /p pcName=Which PC?:
psshutdown -c -k \\%pcName% -r
PAUSE
goto :DONE

:LIST
ECHO[
set /p input=Which list?:
set list=%input%.txt
psshutdown @C:\Temp\Lists\%list% -r -f else goto :SKIP
PAUSE
goto :DONE

:SKIP
ECHO[
ECHO You probably typed something wrong. Starting from the top.
PAUSE
ECHO[
goto :SET

:DONE
ECHO Mischief Managed
TIMEOUT /t 10
EXIT /B
```

Every time I run either the PC logic or the List logic the prompt merely shows me the psshutdown syntax uses. I have tried every configuration of syntax I can find on the internet. Any thoughts?

Edit:It's worth noting that the @file syntax I'm using works almost verbatim with psexec.

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out to me.  If your filename has a space in it, that would produce the results you mentioned.  Try putting quotes around the file path.

I also can't make sense of the "else" statement at the end of your line.  Was that a mistake?  It should work with the below line instead.

```
psshutdown @"C:\Temp\Lists\%list%" -r -f
```

Comment: The "else" is left over from logic that would stop the command if the list didn't exist. It would run the "goto :SKIP" anyway so I scrapped it. I meant to delete it before pasting. 

The filename does not have spaces in it. The result is the same when using the PC name which also has no spaces. It seems to not like something about the batch file itself as running the exact same command in a cmd prompt works fine.

Comment: Hmm.  That's weird.  Just guessing here, but have you tried enabling delayed variable expansion?  I wonder if that has any affect on how psshutdown loops through the computers.